# $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)-g(x)$ and Asymptotic Equivalence

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

I'm confused about asymptotic equivalence.

I read on a textbook that, supposing  $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=+\infty$,

$\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)-g(x)= l \in \mathbb{R} \implies f(x) \sim g(x) $

Is this true?

If so are there other cases in which the limit $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)-g(x)$ is related to asymptotic equivalence?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(I assume the definition of equivalence you start with is $\frac{f}{g}\to 1$).*

Since both $f(x)\to\infty$, $g(x)\to\infty$ when $x\to\infty$ (for $g$, this is easy to see given that $f$ goes to infinity and the difference converges to $\ell$), we know that for $x$ big enough both $f(x),g(x) > 0$ (and we can divide by $g(x)$).

Then,

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f(x)-g(x)}{g(x)} + 1 \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} 1$$
as the first term has its numerator going to $\ell\in\mathbb{R}$ and the denominator going to $\infty$. This means that $f\operatorname*{\sim}_{c}g$ indeed.

In general, you can actually define the equivalence $f\operatorname*{\sim}_{c}g$ as $f-g = o(g)$ (at $c$). (and this is often a definition used, since it does not rely on a ratio that can involve dividing by $0$)

Comment: Sorry, I meant "the relation of being equivalent (at $c$)." (IIRC, this *is* an equivalence relation)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have two questions: is this valid only for $x\to \infty$ or also for $x\to c \in \mathbb{R}$? And is the reverse of the implication proposed true in general? (I suppose the answer to the second question is no because it is not sure that $o(g)=l \in \mathbb{R}$)

Comment: It is also valid for $x\to c$. But the implication is only one way: think for instance of $f(x) = x+\ln x$ and $g(x)=x$: you do have $f\sim_\infty g$, yet $f-g \to \infty$. (i.e., the difference is still $o(g)$, but goes to infinity)

Comment: Thanks! But considering these two functions $f=x+5$ and $g=x$ as $x\to 0$. We have $f-g\to 5 $ but $lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{f}{g}=+\infty$. Is this wrong?

Comment: @Gianolepo With your example, $f$ and $g$ are **not** equivalent at $0$, so the result indeed makes sense. (They are equivalent at $\infty$, but not at $0$.) See it that way: if they were equivalent at $0$, they would "behave" roughly the same when $x\to0$: but one goes to $0$, while the other goes to $5$

Comment: Ok! I think I misunderstood, so if I find that $f-g \to l \in \mathbb{R}$ when $x\to c \in \mathbb{R}$  I cannot say that $f \sim g$ when $x \to c$?

Comment: Look at your assumptions in the original question: you still need the assumption $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = \infty$. (You need a bit less actually: what you require is $f-g = o(g)$ at $c$, which is in particular satisfied if $f-g\to_c \ell$ and $f\to_c \infty$.)